# How to set one variable equal to the sum of 2 other variables in cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

My code is

```
FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1-6" %%G IN ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Hour^,Minute^,Month^,Second^,Year /Format:table') DO (
   IF "%%~L"== "" goto s_done
      Set _yyyy=%%L
      Set _mm=00%%J
      Set /a _nextmm=_mm+1
)
:s_done
```

What I want is this variable "_nextmm" = this variable "_mm" + 1

But when I run this code. It's result is

```
IF "2021" == "" goto s_done
Set _yyyy = 2021
Set _mm = 008
Set /a _nextmm = _mm+1
```

And I call `echo %_nextmm%`. The result is 1 instead of 009.

What did I do wrong in here?

Comment: You need delayedexpansion.

Comment: Hi @Gerhard Thank for your reply. I don't understand what you said. I'm new with this. So please more detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope there are no <kbd>SPACEs</kbd> around the equal-to signs in your actual `set` command lines as they would harm. The best way is this syntax:

```cmd
rem /* No spaces around `=`-sign, and quotes around the whole assignment expression,
rem    which avoids unwanted training whitepsaces and protects special characters;
rem    without assigning the quotes themselves to the variable value: */
set "VAR=Value"
```

---

Anyway, use:

```cmd
set /A "_nextmm=%%J+1"
```

instead of `set /A _nextmm=_mm+1`, because (as I assume) `%%J` is `8`, which is a correct decimal number, but `_mm` is `008`, which is treated as an **octal number due to the leading zeros** (yes, I know, this is not intuitive, but take a look at [this](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html#expressions)), which is invalid as there are only digits `0` to `7`, hence `0` is taken for further arithmetic operations.

---

If you have your `echo` command line *within* the body of the `for /F` loop (so before the closing `)`), use:

```cmd
for /F … (
    …
    call echo %%_nextmm%%
)
```

or use [delayed variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html):

```cmd
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F … (
    …
    echo !_nextmm!
)
endlocal
```

If you have your `echo` command line *outside* of the body of the `for /F` loop (so after the closing `)`), normal or immediate expansion will work as expected:

```cmd
for /F … (
    …
)
echo %_nextmm%
```

Answer (score 1):

TBH, I'm not sure of your logic, because if this was done in December 2021, then adding 1 would make the month incorrectly `13`, and the year would remain as `2021`.

For that reason, it would be much better if you just used PowerShell to assist you instead of WMIC. PowerShell sees dates as objects not strings, so you can perform the math directly in order to define the required values for your variables.

```sh
For /F "Tokens=1-2" %%G In ('
 %SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile
 -Command "(Get-Date).AddMonths(1).ToString('yyyy MM')"') Do (Set "_yyyy=%%G"
    Set "_MM=%%H")
```

If you wanted to do it without splitting the line up for better reading then:

```sh
For /F "Tokens=1-2" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "(Get-Date).AddMonths(1).ToString('yyyy MM')"') Do Set "_yyyy=%%G" & Set "_MM=%%H"
```